# Is it possible to make a text follow an object assign to an avatar's rig?

Tags: rigging, transforms, text-object

I'm making an ID card that moves with an avatar's rig/armature. It's assigned to the avatar spine.
But I need an editable text name that can be changed by the client, and I'm out of ideas to make the text move with the avatar's spine too.
I've tried to "parent" the text to the ID card and I also tried to add the "Child of" constraint to the text, putting the ID card as the target.
But when I move the avatar, and rotate the body the text moves differently from the ID card, it does not follow the card perfectly.

Anybody knows how can I do it?
And also, can anybody explain me?
[image]

[image]

Comment: At first glance, that should work, so something additional is making it not work. I think it’s blend-exchange.com time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select text,
- select the mesh object you want to attach the text to,
- hit Tab to enter edit mode,
- select 3 vertices that you wish to attach the text object to
- hit ctrl+p.
- You should get a prompt asking if you want to make vertex parent, hit OK, obviously.

That's it - the text object is parented to the 3 vertices so now it follows them even if the geometry is deformed.

3 vertices are required so it is possible to match child's orientation to them, so you should choose some 3 vertices that form a nice triangle and not a straight line. If the triangle of the chosen vertices gets deformed into whatever orientation, that orientation will be inherited by the child objects.

Comment: I've just tried it. But when I go to the armature and rotate the spine, the text (on the bottom) rotates different from the ID card
photo:
https://imgur.com/MNXzj8e

Comment: Did you attach it to the ID card? Did you use 3 vertices as opposed to 1?

Comment: Yes.. I've uploaded the file to show you
https://www.mediafire.com/file/59u5h657ald320u/id_card_jogo_1.blend/file

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. You have used 3 vertices in a straight line. 3 vertices are required to get a rotation value. If they are in a straight line, the tiniest binary rounding errors define rotation that's why it spins unpredictably. Choose vertices that form a triangle.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeess!! It worked!! Thank you veeeery much!!! ♥ I was about to get crazy!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider upvoting and/or accepting answers on this platform if they are useful or answer your questions.

Comment: Ok. I still cant give the feedback! I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. :( But it was recorded