# origin not moving with pmx model when playing animation

Tags: parent, origin, mmd-tools

I import the model using mmdtools. I want to create a child parent relationship between a group of lights and the model so there's no weird shadows. It works perfectly fine in object mode however when I start playing the animation the origin does not follow the mesh or the bones, therefore the lights are also not moved. I tried set origin to 3d cursor but failed. And all other option in 'set origin' menu doesn't work for me. The motion data is pmd and I also imported it by mmdtools. I couldn't pack the model data so there's no blend file, sorry. Anything would be really helpful. Another solution of controlling lights would be also appreciated.[image: not moving when playing animation][image: moves with model when grabbed]

Comment: I just answered a similar question. The solution should work for this as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283900/is-it-possible-to-make-a-text-follow-an-object-assign-to-an-avatars-rig/283901?noredirect=1#comment488034_283901

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! Problem solved! This really helped me a lot